# Self-hosted phaser 3 library: this is undefined?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, self-hosting

I am **absolutely new with phaser 3**.

I have installed the library with npm. Then I naively fetch the bundled file from *node_modules*.

```
<body>
    <script src="./node_modules/phaser/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/start.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I load *index.html* in the browser as file, it works fine. But now I have created a little v-host in my Apache and let it serve the files. This works too, but phaser yells at me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.texture is undefined
    setFrame http://game.localhost/personwar/node_modules/phaser/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.js:138726
    setTexture http://game.localhost/personwar/node_modules/phaser/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.js:138699
    Image http://game.localhost/personwar/node_modules/phaser/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.js:29328
    <anonymous> http://game.localhost/personwar/node_modules/phaser/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.js:168386
    create http://game.localhost/personwar/js/start.js:34
    [...]
    DOMContentLoaded http://game.localhost/personwar/node_modules/phaser/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.js:86811
    Game http://game.localhost/personwar/node_modules/phaser/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.js:154945
    <anonymous> http://game.localhost/personwar/js/start.js:17
```

I have stolen *start.js* from the [beginner tutorial](https://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3/part5) and here it all starts:

```
function create () {
    console.log('this', this);
    this.add.image(0, 0, 'bg').setOrigin(0, 0);
    ...
}
```

I don't understand, why `this.texture` changes when the library is self hosted, compared to being delivered by `file://`. What do I need to change here?

It might be a timing problem, maybe I need to setup smth else before calling `this.add.image` in the `create` callback.

I will go on with investigating, what *texture* actually is.

### Issue were Header, which was set by server: Content-Security-Policy

The rule `"default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'"`

blocked this call

*blob:http://game.localhost/b6ac3ad7-e25b-4b82-8d07-8f4ce6c331c3*

which was the call for one of our images. This is weird and I don't get it. But the point is: **no image loaded -> no texture**.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know which file your are linking. the main phaser file is  called **phaser.js** or **phaser.min.js**. I think this is the root of your problem.

The easy solution is to download the phaser javascript file into your webfolder, or link it from a cdn. (https://phaser.io/download/stable)

If you (want to) use **npm** you will need a bundler like ***webpack, parcel***, ... there are serval templates out there. (like this one https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-project-template).

> **btw.:** *I'm no expert, but I would in general never have the `node_modules` directory in a webserver accessible folder (if not really needed, and if you are running apache, it is probably not needed), since this could create be a potential security risk.*

Comment: The file is delivered correctly: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/dist/phaser.js The problem occurrs in `setFrame` (ll. 146449ff): `this.texture` is undefined. So my question is wrong and I'll fix it. This could be a timing problem? `setFrame` is called in my `create` callback, via `this.add.image`.

Comment: Uuh, I've found the problem and a workaround, see edits!

Comment: wihout seening the whole code it is difficult to find the error.  if the original sample code doesn't run selfhosted your setup code is incorrect, if it works then your phaser code is the problem.

Comment: @BairDev good to read the it works. thank you for sharing.